# Adding interactive 3D object into WinForms project

Tags: c#, winforms, 3d, tic-tac-toe

so I'm making this 3D TTT game and I'd love to add a 3D interactive cube for live feedback, because the game as it is may be hard to grasp by greater audience.

I've chosen Visual Studio 2013 for my project and I write it in C#. The game looks like 7 isolated squares containing 7^2 buttons. My idea is to add a 7^3 cube of 343 cells for better navigation to the form. Obviously, each cell within the cube would have to be linked with each WF button.

So far I've spent goodly time on the internet and even my IT teacher was unable to provide this answer, so I come to you. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try SlimDX:  http://slimdx.org/ It is a  free open source framework that enables developers to easily build DirectX applications using C#

OpenTK http://www.opentk.com/ is another option.